# Moving LXD containers to clean install of 16.04

Tags: lxc, 16.04, lxd

I have a load (~14) of LXD containers running on my 14.04 development machine.

I would like to do a clean install of 16.04 but I need to keep my containers.

What is the best approach to achieve this?

Should I publish the containers as images and then create new containers using those images when 16.04 is installed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**On your old Ubuntu 14.04:**

1. Publish your Container:

   ```
   lxc publish --force 'name of container" --alias 'new name'
   ```

   Example:

   ```
   lxc publish --force 'lxc-wordpress' --alias 'lxc-image-wordpress'
   ```
2. Export image:

   ```
   lxc image  export 'new name'
   ```

The output is something like this:

```
efaa243331f0a7c175376edaf796545a01ad09bb47f25a297b798e09fe66ee66.tar.gz
```

Show size of export:

```
    du -h efaa243331f0a7c175376edaf796545a01ad09bb47f25a297b798e09fe66ee66.tar.gz
```

3. Backup your export image.
4. Backup your containers profile/s
   you can show with:

   ```
   lxc profile list
   ```

You can save your *tar.gz in whatever secure place.

**Install Ubuntu 16.04.2 and configure your LXD environment**

Copy your backup image and, inside their directory, start import

1. Import your container images:

   ```
    lxc image import efaa243331f0a7c175376edaf796545a01ad09bb47f25a297b798e09fe66ee66.tar.gz --alias lxc-image-wordpress
   ```
2. Create and start your container based on your image:

   ```
    lxc launch lxc-image-wordpress lxc-wordpress
   ```